# Does ews-java-api work with microsoft exchange 365?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

Has any one used ews-java-api to retrieve calendar data from microsoft exchange 365 ? If so are there any help links or document that you can share ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using the documentation for the ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api), you can use this method to get all appointments on the calendar between startDate and endDate in the specified folder, including recurring meeting occurrences.

```
public void findAppointments(CalendarFolder folder, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date startDate = formatter.parse("2010-05-01 12:00:00");
    Date endDate = formatter.parse("2010-05-30 13:00:00");
    CalendarFolder cf=CalendarFolder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
    FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = cf.findAppointments(new CalendarView(startDate, endDate));
    for (Appointment appt : findResults.getItems()) {
        System.out.println("SUBJECT====="+appt.getSubject());
        System.out.println("BODY========"+appt.getBody());
    }
}
```

Do note, there are things you need to setup prior to implementing this method, I recommend reading the github documentation.